# jquery - how to select for this, get a count, and get the current position within the selected group

Tags: jquery

I have a set of img boxes that are marked up like this

I want to get a count and have this:

```
<div data-location-id="6" class="img-box-set">my img</div>
```

I have:

```
var location_id = $(this).data('location-id');
// fixed per comment #1 below
var count_of=$('.img-box-set[data-location-id='+location_id+']').length;
alert("here is count_of" + count_of);
```

but the length always returns 0. Am I doing something wrong with selector or with length property?

Also, assuming I have 4, how would I determine which position I'm in (either 0-based or 1-based)?

thx

**edit #1**
So I'd think this works but it isn't (per @jack ) and index docs. (update - this does work; had syntax error)

```
var index_box=$('.img-box-set[data-location-id='+location_id+']').index(this);
alert("here is the index" + index_box);
```

Comment: Using `[]` is an attribute selector.. Try using `[data-location-id='+location_id+']'`

Comment: duh, sorry - working now. thx, brewing coffee now. any idea on how to get current positon back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".img-box-set").each(function(index,value){

   alert(index);// The position of image box set

   var location_id = $(this).data('location-id');
   var count_of=$('.img-box-set[data-location-id="'+location_id+'"]').length;
   alert("here is count_of" + count_of);


});
```

If you want to know the length of all `.img-box-set` then you can simply write

`$(".img-box-set").length` in the function

**POSITION**

You can run  inside your function

```
 var elem_id =$(this).attr("id");
 var pos=-1; 
  $(".img-box-set").each(function(index,value){ 

     if($(this).attr("id")==elem_id){
        pos=index;
     }
});
alert(pos);
```

The selector can be `$(".img-box-set")` or `$('.img-box-set[data-location-id="'+location_id+'"]')`  according to your requirement.

Comment: thx - so i edited above for the location_id - was my mistake. So to get the index? like 0 or 1 for the first. Basically, this is firing in response to a mouseover so I want to be 0/1 of 4 over first and 1/2 of 4 over 2nd

Comment: it will be too lengthy for comment. I'm adding it to answer

Comment: shouldn't I just be able to grab via the selector and get the index of the evented selector from within the selection? Seems like should be a one-liner

Comment: Try once `var index_box=$('.img-box-set[data-location-id='+location_id+']').index(this);` You missed `.` before index. if still does not work then try `var index_box=$('.img-box-set[data-location-id='+location_id+']').index($(this));
`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to search on `.data()`, you can do this:

```
var count = $('.img-box-set')
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('location-id') == location_id;
    })
    .length
```

The position is returned by using [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)